# Is there any downside to metal armor over leather armor?

Tags: fallout-4

In New Vegas, metal armor made your sneaking less likely to be successful. Is there anything like this in Fallout 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as the sneak factor of an armor is also determined by its weight-class. The heavier the armor, the less sneaky it is. You can also modify it to increase its stealth if the metal armor proves to be heavier.

Comment: Also metal armor is typically much weaker against energy and radiation

Comment: I'm been looking for confirmation of this and haven't seen it so far. Is there some way to see this indicated in-game, or was there a loading-screen tip about it? FO3 and FONV gave specific cues by listing an armor's class (light, medium, heavy) and by telling you that lighter armor is better for sneaking. So far I haven't noticed anything like that in FO4.

Comment: Its confirmed as early in the game (when in vault 111) the games gives you a hint in stealth an it talks about the weight of the armor corresponding to the stealth of the player

Answer (score 5):

Metal armor *tends* to be heavier than a corresponding piece of leather armor. However, this may not be true depending on the mods. Lighter armor is better for sneaking, so **assuming the same mods, leather armor will be sneakier**.

However, this weight issue isn't particular to metal armor. Any heavier armor, including a piece of leather armor with heavier mods, will be less sneaky than a lighter piece.

What *is* particular to metal armor vs leather armor are the resistances. **Leather armor has high energy resist and low physical resist. Metal is the opposite, with high physical resist and low energy resistance.** This is the main difference.